# nginx: use different server for different path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, server

I have two Rails applications sitting behind two different URIs on the same machine. The nginx configuration is for each application in an own configuration file.

Now one of the applications has to be slowly merged into the second one. There is an endpoint accessible under the URI path `application-one.com/register`. I want only this `application-one.com/register` path to be accessing the second application and all other paths `(application-one.com/* except /register)` still accessing the first application.

Is there a way to do this without using 301 Redirects since I am not able to use them in my case?

An example configuration file looks like this:

```
upstream unicorn_application_one {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn_application_one.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    client_max_body_size ....
    ...
    server_name application-one.com

    root /home/deployer/application_one/current/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn_application_one;

    location @unicorn_application_one {
        proxy_set_header ...
        ....
    }

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        ...
    }

    ....
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried @joaumg approach but I had to change it:

Whenever I extracted an upstream to an external file I got a `duplicate upstream` error.

So I just changed the location from @joaumg's code to:

```
location /register {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/unicorn_application_two.sock;
}
```

Is there a way to do it in the way @joaumg is telling without having a duplicate upstream error?

Comment: You can use an internal redirect based on the path in the server block.

Comment: thanks @joaumg. could you possibly post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible example (untested):

> cat upstreams.conf

```
upstream unicorn_application_one {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn_application_one.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream unicorn_application_two {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn_application_two.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

> cat server_one.conf

```
include upstreams.conf;

server {
    client_max_body_size ....
    ...
    server_name application-one.com

    root /home/deployer/application_one/current/public;

    location /register {
        proxy_pass @unicorn_application_two;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn_application_one;

    location @unicorn_application_one {
        proxy_set_header ...
        ....
    }

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        ...
    }


    ....
}
```

Comment: is it fine to have an upstream in both files ?

Comment: You mean two upstreams in the same file ? Sure, if you are worried of changing the url in one file and forgetting to change it in another, you can [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) them, so you would have an `upstream.nginx.conf`, or something like it.

Comment: I mean having ``upstream unicorn_application_two`` declared in two files like ``application-one.conf (which would be the one you posted`` and ``application-two.conf (where it was already before)``

Comment: Now that you did mention it, quite sure it throws an error, however, you can unify them in a external file with the [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) as I mentioned previously. ( Edited the answer to better reflect this ;D )

Comment: Thanks a lot @joaumg. I edited my answer. Maybe you have an idea why I had this error?

Comment: @Chris, are you sure you have only ONE DEFINITION of the upstream in ALL config files ? This is, you moved it to `upstream.conf`, and everywhere you are using it you are including this file ?

Comment: yes I'm sure. I just used `grep` once again on all files but I have the definition only in one file. It appears to me that if the definition is used in two files (by including) that this is a duplicate as well, don't know if that can be...

Comment: Could you move the `upstreams.conf` to nginx's conf file (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/*`)? And remove the includes from the `sites-enabled/` files? Since the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` will include all the config files before reading the server blocks.